# how to find pattern and insert text in middle using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to add a `name` in the middle of `dirPath`

```
#!/bin/bash

name='agent_name-2'
dirPath='/var/azp/1/s'
```

I want to insert `agent_name-2` after `/var/azp` in `dirPath`, and store it in a separate variable `result` like this

```
result=/var/azp/agent_name-2/1/s
```

Comment: What pattern do you want to find exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Do you want a generic solution that can insert `agent_name-2` into a path like `/var/local/6/t`, or `/var/baq/3/t`, or `/usr/azp/1/2/3/s`?  If so, exactly what are the criteria to determine where to insert?  Or do you just want to exactly match `/1/s`....in which case just write `result=/var/azp/"${name}"/1/s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/var/azp` is a hard coded string (i.e. constant), try:

```sh
name='agent_name-2'
dirPath='/var/azp/1/s'
result="/var/azp/$name${dirPath#/var/azp}"
```

Explanation: `${dirPath#/var/azp}` removes the string `/var/azp` from the beginning of the string `$dirPath`.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash search-replace

You can use Bash's search and replace syntax `${variable//search/replace}`.

```
prefix='/var/azp'
result=${dirPath//$prefix/$prefix\/$name}
# > /var/azp/agent_name-2/1/s
```

### `sed s`

If `$name` doesn't contain any special characters, you could inject it into a `sed` search-replace:

```
$ sed "s|/var/azp|\0/$name|" <<< "$dirPath"
/var/azp/agent_name-2/1/s
```

Then for saving the result to a variable, see [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

name='agent_name-2'
dirPath='/var/azp/1/s'
```

Split `dirPath` by `/` and store it in the array `dirs`.

```sh
IFS=/ read -r -a dirs <<< "$dirPath"
```

Calculate the middle of the array.

```sh
middle=$(((${#dirs[@]}+1)/2))
```

Create two new arrays `left` and `right` with the left and right half of the `dirs` array.

```sh
left=("${dirs[@]:0:$middle}")
right=("${dirs[@]:$middle}")
```

Join the left and right half and put the `name` in between.

```sh
result="$(printf "%s/" "${left[@]}" "$name" "${right[@]}")"
```

Remove the trailing slash.

```sh
result=${result%/}
```